# Бинарный файл: запись/чтение (с++)

Tags: c++, файлы, binary

Такой вопрос - как правильно записывать и считывать строки из бинарного файла?
Дело в том, что в файл записываю вектор `vector<string>words` поэлементно:

```
fstream tab("tab.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    tab.write((char*)&words[i], 20); 
}
tab.close();
```

и считываю во временный массив(пропуская каждый второй):

```
    char x[21];
    fstream show("tab.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    show.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    int length = show.tellg();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size()/2; i++){
        show.read((char*)&x, 20);
        cout << x << endl;
        length+=20;
        show.seekg(length);
    }
    show.close();
```

выводит непонятные символы.
расскажите новичку, пожалуйста, как это правильно делать?

Comment: Объясните, что именно вы хотите записать в файл.

Comment: говорю же, вектор.
вектор состоит из слов(нулевой и каждый чётный элемент - слова) и их порядковым номеров (каждый нечетный элемент). требуется создать таблицу при помощи бинарного файла из записей фиксированной длины и создать упорядоченный список.

Comment: необходимо модифицировать следующую программу под слова:
http://pastebin.com/NaLWWuMu

Answer (score 3):

```
tab.write((char*)&words[i], 20);
```

Объясните, xто именно хочется записать в файл? Если мусор, то именно он и пишется туда, вполне успешно.

Для сохранения таких сложных структур, как плюсовый вектор, нельзя писать "сырые" данные. Это - служебная информация самого класса vector, которая к вашим данным не имеет никакого отношения. Для каждого типа данных, хранимых в векторе, необходимо разрабатывать средства записи самостоятельно. Проще всего, конечно, именно такой тип данных писать как текст:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    tab << words[i] << "\n" << i << "\n";
}
```

Или даже ещё проще (зачем писать порядковый номер, если строки и так идут по порядку?):

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    tab << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

Но если хочется именно двоичный формат, то как-то так, например (не забываем, что строки - разной длины):

```
fstream tab("tab.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
for(size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    size_t size = words[i].size();
    // пишем в файл длину строки: 
    tab.write( (char *)&size, sizeof(size) );
    // теперь саму строку: 
    tab.write( words[i].c_str(), size );
}
tab.close();
```

Ну и читать:

```
fstream show("tab.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
for( size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++ )
{
    size_t size;
    // читаем длину очередной строки:
    show.read( (char *)&size, sizeof(size) );
    // читаем саму строку:
    char buf[size + 1];
    show.read( buf, size );
    buf[size] = 0;
    // нечётные записи пропускаем:
    if( !(i % 2) )
    {
        // с чётными что-то делаем:
        cout << i < ": " << buf << "\n";
    }
}
show.close();
```

Чтобы сделать записи одной длины, можно сначала вычислить максимальную длину строки в векторе, и создавать записи как структуры:

```
struct _rec 
{ 
    size_t order; char word[1];
} *rec = (_rec *)new char[ sizeof(_rec) + N ];

for( size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++ )
{
    memset( rec->word, 0, N+1 );
    strcpy( rec->word, words[i].c_str() );
    rec->order = i; // не знаю что сюда писать и откуда брать
    tab.write( (char *)rec, sizeof(_rec)+N );
}
```

Ну и:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); i++ )
{
    show.read( (char *)rec, sizeof(_rec)+N );
    cout << rec->order << ": " << rec->word << "\n"
}
```

P.P.S. Можно, конечно, потом всё это (чтение и запись элементов) оформить в виде `operator <<` и `operator >>`.

Comment: в файл необходимо записать вектор. вектор состоит из слов(нулевой и каждый чётный элемент - слова) и их порядковым номеров (каждый нечетный элемент). требуется создать таблицу при помощи бинарного файла из записей фиксированной длины и создать упорядоченный список.

Comment: Дописал кое-что в ответ

Comment: попытаюсь разобраться, конечно, но весь этот геморрой, который я пытаюсь реализовать, от формулировки задания. нужны записи фиксированной длины. пользователь сам должен указывать последовательность слов.
например(ввод):
London 2
is 1
the 5
capital 3
....
содержание списка: is London the ....

Comment: Ну, добавить к записи ещё одно число (порядковый номер) не проблема. Если же нужны обязательно записи одинаковой длины, то сейчас допишу.

Comment: с записью, выводом и слов, и чисел, справилась. спасибо. теперь осталось реализовать поочередный вывод вместо обычного с использованием seekg.