# Как сохранить структуру в файл, а потом прочитать ее?

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры, struct, fstream

Хочу создать программу, которая сохраняет структуру в векторами, другими структурами и тд:

```
struct b {
    bool complited;
    std::vector<int> nums;
};

struct a {
    bool complited;
    std::vector<b> list;
};
```

Затем сохраняю объект структуры a в файл:

```
a dataToSave = { false, { { false, { 1, 2, 3 } } } };
int dataSize = sizeof(dataToSave);

FILE* fileWrite;
fileWrite = fopen("save.dat", "w");
fwrite(&dataToSave, dataSize, 1, fileWrite);
fclose(fileWrite);
```

После этого хочу отобразить один из элемента, загружая файл вновь, однако ловлю исключение:

```
a dataToLoad;
FILE* fileRead;
fileRead = fopen("save.dat", "r");
fread(&dataToLoad, dataSize, 1, fileRead);
fclose(fileRead);

std::cout << dataToLoad.list[0].nums[1];
```

Как это решить, подскажите пожалуйста. Код исключения:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF7F50E61AA в Save.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: `std::vector` - динамическая структура и внутри использует выделение памяти. Поэтому не выйдет сохранить и прочитать вашим способом. Если коротко, то вы сохраняете _указатели_.

Comment: А можно создать что-нибудь по типу динамического массива, чтобы работало. Типо list = new int(10)?

Comment: free(): double free detected in tcache 2 ругает gcc. структуру с вектором так нельзя читать/писать. и потом советую sizeof(struct a) использовать.

Comment: @МарияК. [вектор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) - это обертка над указателем на динамическую память. Вам нужно в "ручную" сохранять его размер и данные. При том что у вас вложенные вектора, то "ручное" сохранение нужно и для дочерних элементов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка сохранения сложной структуры в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910758/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Comment: [Бинарный файл: запись/чтение (с++)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420525)

Comment: [Запись объекта класса в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816254)